# PHP - SQL Select filter between two tables on id

Tags: php, sql, select

could someone help me fix the below code please:

```
  $decision = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['decision']);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE 'fao' LIKE '%decision%' AND id NOT IN 
   (SELECT id FROM assigned)";

  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

`fao` field only ever has two values, `Nurse` or `Dietitian`. The issue is with my `SELECT` statement. In the `assigned` table, there are two columns, an `id` value and the name of a user. What I am trying to do is if the `id` value exists in 'assigned' table, then I would like to remove this from the results of SELECTing all from 'user1'. I am then echoing these results into a table. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much Bhaskar, that worked a treat!